# Jquery not working in angular 6 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

Tags: jquery, angular, angular6

I am in process migrating Angular 5 project to Angular 6.

While starting application by

```
npm start
```

getting the below error

```
 ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 9000, 
open your browser on http://localhost:9000/ **
91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,open'\trunk\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'
```

I tried

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Nothing is working

I checked my node modules folder I can able to see the jquery file

Pasted my package.json and angular.json below

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.3",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
"typescript": "~2.7.2",
"@angular/cli": "~6.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.3.0",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "~5.9.1"
}
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./assets/css/font-icon.css",
          "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's so easy. just remove one DOT from path in styles array and scripts array like: "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Once again the angular team makes things harder for not real reason =(

I had this problem and after Googling around fruitlessly I wondered if they had changed relative paths somehow as well as renaming angular-cli.json.

A little further up in the file I found the line:

Yeah, just change:

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

to

```
"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. So Angular 6 changed how they locate node packages also.

Comment: Seriously what the... this change about node packages should have been more broadcasted... thanks for your answer!

Comment: It worked for me after replacing "../node_module*" with "node_modules*". I am using angular 8

Comment: but where to do such changes. I mean going in which directory??

Comment: this does not work in angular 12. I keep getting no such file error, nothing to do with syntax looks like it.

Answer (score 7):

In Angular 6 u don't need to write:

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

You can write with `./` like on the top this will works too, but the easiest way in `angular.json` file:

```
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

In my opinion it's better and clear

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.
It appears the installation doesn't update the package.json file unless "--save" is included in the "npm install" command.

In other words, the packages should be installed with

```
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save popper.js
```

Answer (score 5):

For Angular 6 the path is as follows:

**from**:

```
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

**to**

```
"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"./node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error
`An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js does not exist.`

try installing:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
npm install bootstrap --save
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 12 I had no preceding dots and slashes but in order to resolve this error I had to add them.

So I changed

```
node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

to

```
./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
```

in angular.json file

Answer (score 1):

Install `@ngBootstrap` with this `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
 and `npm install jquery --save` or
`npm install @types/jquery --save` after the installation go to `angular.json` and locate where

```
"styles": [
              {
                "input": "styles.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
```

and change it to this :

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

and `ng server --open` to run your project

Answer (score 1):

For me, type this command `npm install jquery --save` in the same directory of repository and it works. Even I already had `jquery.js` under the directory of `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

In your file 'tsconfig.json', you make maybe

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2017",
    "dom"
  ]
 },
"include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts",  "src/**/*.ts"], 
}
```

You can replace

```
"include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts",  "src/**/*.ts"],
```

to

```
"include": ["src/**/*.ts","node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts" ],
```

Moreover, in your file 'angular.json', I delete '../' in front of node_modules in "styles" and "scripts".

And I copied lines of the "scripts" in the "scripts" in the category "test"

```
"test": {
     ...
     "styles": [
       "src/styles.css"
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "./assets/css/font-icon.css",
        "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
     ],
     "scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
     ],
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative path `../` used to go back one directory. So, first check the file path, if its not contain your project root folder you are searching that jquery file somewhere else that even not exist.

If node_modules file and angular.json both in same directory you donot need to use relative path.

**In Angular 6, you donot need to use relative path** to go inside node_modules from angular.json(`../` or even like `./`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue...

The `Jquery` plugin didn't have an `npm package` ready : (
 So I decided to put it inside the assets folder...
 Evidently that didn't work.
 so I did some testing...

Here's what worked for me:

- Navigate to `node_modules/jquery/dist/`
- — and simply insert the plugin file there.
- Once this is done change your angular.json file
  from:

  "scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../assets/libraries/okshadow.min.js"
  ]

To:

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/okshadow.min.js"
]
```

And your all set!

P.S. This is on `Angular 7.0` rather than `Angular 6`

Answer (score 0):

"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
not
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

We don't use a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Paths in angular-cli.json are relative to the project root (src/ normally). For instance, you have the src/styles.css file, but in angular-cli.json it's listed only as styles.css.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to run "npm install -g @angular/cli" command when you created your app.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by removing `../` and `./`

```json
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```