# Alertify Error "ReferenceError: alertify is not defined " in Angular 6

Tags: angular, alertifyjs

I try to use alertify.js in my project .So I followed this material https://signl.uk/tutorial/index/notify-service-with-angular-5. But I got a error `ReferenceError: alertify is not defined` when click button in my application.

alertifyjs css and js files I add into **angular.json** file.

[image: ![enter image description here]

**alertify.service.ts**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Help me for identify my mistake.

**Edit**

I import AlertifyService in component.ts file as `private alertify: AlertifyService` and In app module  `import { AlertifyService } from './services/alertify.service';` and added AlertifyService in provider as   `providers: [AlertifyService]`

I use alertify in my login component

**login.component.ts**

```
login(){
let email = this.loginForm.get("email").value;
let password = this.loginForm.get("password").value;
this.loading = true;
this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe(response => {

  this.alertify.success('Successfully Login');

  this.loading = false;

  // Save data to sessionStorage
  localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', "true");
  localStorage.setItem('currentUserID', response.user.uid);
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
}, error => {
  this.loading = false;
 });
}
```

Comment: try `import * as alertify;`

Comment: you need to import

Comment: I import AlertifyService in  component.ts file as `private alertify: AlertifyService `and In app module as `import { AlertifyService } from './services/alertify.service';`

Comment: Have you added `AlertifyService` in `providers:[]` ?

Comment: @Exterminator yes I added it in providers : []

Comment: can you show us the code where are you using this?

Comment: did you restart `ng serve` after adding the script to `angular.json` ?

Comment: @Exterminator I update my post with code

Comment: Can you please check if `alertify.min.js` exists on the given path?

Comment: and remove that `providedIn: root` from `@Injectable`

Comment: @David  I restart `ng serve` then I got error in CLI `no such file or directory, open 'D:\testProject\node_modules\alertifyjs\build\alertify.min.js'`

Comment: Check if it is present there? If yes then try to change the path you have provided in `angular.json` otherwise download file then put it there and provide correct address as well.

Comment: I've seen that tutorial too, the problem for me was that alertify is discontinued, and therefore even though bower recognizes it, the .js files don't get downloaded. You should google alertify.js, download the scripts manually and place them into the folder your app would look for them.

Comment: @Exterminator I download the scripts manually and put file in this path  **node_modules\alertifyjs\build**  then I restart server again I get same CLI error  `no such file or directory, open 'D:\testProject\node_modules\alertifyjs\build\alertify.min.js'` .I use this site for download [https://alertifyjs.com/ ]

Comment: check the path, i think the path you have provided is not correct. Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: @Exterminator My mistake. I refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280975/jquery-not-working-in-angular-6-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open] . `"../node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"  to "./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js" ` then It's work. thank you so much support me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Restart server.
2. If get error like

   `no such file or directory, open 'D:\testProject\node_modules\alertifyjs\build\alertify.min.js'`

then 
Change

`"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "../node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css",
"../node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css",`

to

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css",
"./node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css",
```

Answer (score 2):

you should add to scripts section under the build part.Probably you are adding test section.(in angular.json)

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/shop",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": false,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"

        ]
      },
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, instead of alertifyjs I used alertify.js on both styles.css and angular.json.

```
@import "~alertify.js/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css"; 

"./node_modules/alertify.js/build/alertify.min.js"
```